# Solving recurrence relation $a_n=1 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}ia_{n-i}$ with $a_1=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

> Consider the recurrence relation $$a_n=1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}ia_{n-i}$$ with initial term $a_1=1$. What is $a_n$?

I tried to guess some closed formula from the first 6 terms, which are $1$, $2$, $5$, $13$, $24$, $79$, but no luck.

I tried to use generating functions to solve this sum and inner sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}ia_{n-i}$ seemed to be some kind of convolution of $a_n$ and $b_n=\langle1,1,\dots\rangle$, so this would give us $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}ia_{n-i}b_i$, but I can't solve this.

Lastly, I observed that $a_n - a_{n-1} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i$. But how am i supposed to use it?

I got all this information, but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Your last observation yields $$a_n-a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}a_i=a_{n-1}+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}),$$ hence $$a_n-3a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=0.$$ From here, you are in known territory, right?

Comment: @Did seems to be true, but i just solved this with generating functions and got $$A(x) = \frac{1}{1-3x-x^2}$$ and quickly checked with wolfram. It gave sequence starting with $\langle 1, 3, 10, \dots\rangle$ so it's not quite good. Any idea why is that?

Comment: @Did that doesn't seem to work, for example: $24 - 3(13) + 5 = -10 \neq 0$

Comment: @ZainPatel Yes, the value 24 given in the question is wrong and should read 34.

Comment: @Spinach, the equation of Did didn't work, because $a_n-a_{n-1}\neq\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1}a_i$,i.e. $24-13\neq 1+2+5+13$, the last observation in the question which Did assumed to be correct.

Comment: @Spinach Unless you post the details of what you tried, it is difficult to say why it is wrong.

Comment: @Fernando Huh? $ $

Comment: Ok, I made the calculation with $24$ instead of $34$, all is right then

Comment: Wow, that was very silly mistake of me.
Now it looks like $a_n = Fib(2n-1)$ Seems now its ok. Thanks for your help guys!